# extract specific elements in a string in R

Tags: r, string

I have a series of file names,

```
a<-c("asd1-36457-1-qwe-20.txt","asd-3234-4-qwe-20.txt","asd1-5457-3-qwe-20.txt",
"asd1-546-2-qwe-20.txt","asd1-789-1-qwe-20.txt","asd-542112-7-qwe-20.txt",
"asd-754-4-qwe-20.txt","asd-3466-3-qwe-20.txt","asd-4675-2-qwe-20.txt")
```

I want to extract the second and third blocks between "-" in each file name, and then list these two blocks as two columns in a matrix. I use the following code to proceed:

```
 b<-as.numeric(unlist(Map(function(x) x[2], strsplit(a,"-"))))
 c<-as.numeric(unlist(Map(function(x) x[3], strsplit(a,"-"))))
 cbind(b,c)
```

The result is as follows:

```
           b c
 [1,]  36457 1
 [2,]   3234 4
 [3,]   5457 3
 [4,]    546 2
 [5,]    789 1
 [6,] 542112 7
 [7,]    754 4
 [8,]   3466 3
 [9,]   4675 2
```

It is right. But I wonder whether there is a more convenient way, such as "gsub", to work out this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at `?regexpr` the `parse_one` example at the bottom of the help file shows exactly how to do that with perl-style regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` with `read.csv`.  We match one more characters that are not a `-` from the beginning (`^`) of the string (`[^-]+`) followed by a `-` followed by numbers (`\\d+`) which we place in a capture group (`(...)`) followed by a `-` and another capture group to get the numbers followed by one or more characters (`.*`).  Replace it with the backreference for the capture groups separated by `,`.  This can be used for reading with `read.csv`.

```
read.csv(text=sub("^[^-]+-(\\d+)-(\\d+).*", "\\1,\\2", a), 
                     header=FALSE, col.names = c('b', 'c'))
#       b c
#1  36457 1
#2   3234 4
#3   5457 3
#4    546 2
#5    789 1
#6 542112 7
#7    754 4
#8   3466 3
#9   4675 2
```

---

Or another option is with `fread` where we can `select` the columns of interest

```
library(data.table)
fread(paste(a, collapse="\n"), sep="-", select = 2:3, col.names = c('b', 'c'))
#        b c
#1:  36457 1
#2:   3234 4
#3:   5457 3
#4:    546 2
#5:    789 1
#6: 542112 7
#7:    754 4
#8:   3466 3
#9:   4675 2
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar but somewhat shorter approach with yours would be:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(a, "-"), `[`, c(2,3)))
      [,1]     [,2]
 [1,] "36457"  "1" 
 [2,] "3234"   "4" 
 [3,] "5457"   "3" 
 [4,] "546"    "2" 
 [5,] "789"    "1" 
 [6,] "542112" "7" 
 [7,] "754"    "4" 
 [8,] "3466"   "3" 
 [9,] "4675"   "2"
```

Answer (score 0):

A followup to akrun's answer:

```
> read.table(text=a, sep='-', col.names=letters[1:5])
     a      b c   d      e
1 asd1  36457 1 qwe 20.txt
2  asd   3234 4 qwe 20.txt
3 asd1   5457 3 qwe 20.txt
4 asd1    546 2 qwe 20.txt
5 asd1    789 1 qwe 20.txt
6  asd 542112 7 qwe 20.txt
7  asd    754 4 qwe 20.txt
8  asd   3466 3 qwe 20.txt
9  asd   4675 2 qwe 20.txt
```

Then you can slice this down to just the two columns you want.